# Text disappears when viewed on smartphone

Tags: css, padding, window-resize

When viewing the website on my iPhone (or when I resize the browser), the text in the About Me section of the footer partially disappears on the right hand side of the window.

When I remove the padding from #footer .wrap, none of the text disappears from the browser window.  At it's current value, the padding is 10px 15px.

Ideally, I'd like to keep some sort of padding instead of setting it to zero (or removing it), while obviously having all of the text appear in the browser.

Website: http://www.josephruscitti.com/clients/vickieats/

Screenshot: http://imageshack.us/a/img534/3144/xhx0.jpg

Comment: Is there also a `width:100%;`  set for this element? :) if there is - remove it and enjoy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove width: 100%; from here on the mobile media:

```
#footer-widgets {
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    border-top: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    clear: both;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
```